# Restclient throwing unusual exception

Tags: ruby, ffi, rest-client

While trying to use the following gems:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'restclient'
require 'mechanize'
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- ffi_c (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.10-x86-mingw32/lib/ffi.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.10-x86-mingw32/lib/ffi.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0-x86-mingw32/lib/restclient/windows/root_certs.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0-x86-mingw32/lib/restclient/windows.rb:7:in `require_relative'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0-x86-mingw32/lib/restclient/windows.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0-x86-mingw32/lib/restclient.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:133:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:133:in `rescue in require'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
        from parse_docs.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

Since the last thing on this list is line 5, which is `require 'restclient'` I'm guessing it has something to do with that? However I've attempted to do the following:

- Since `restclient` is deprecated and has moved to `rest-client`, I tried using `rest-client` however that doesn't work and produces the same error.
- I've also attempted to `require 'rubygems'` but that when I run the program, it will not allow me to continue and produces the same error.
- So I completely took out `restclient`, this is how I got the idea that `restclient` is causing the problem , because without it there, the program can run successfully.
- So I though what would happen if I rolled back on `ffi`? So I installed the `ffi` version that is needed to run `restclient` However, that didn't help either.
- Updated all my gems, still throwing the same error..
- Downloaded the latest version on `ffi`, nothing changes, except now I havea new version of `ffi` on my system, that's still throwing an error when being used with `restclient`

Why is `restclient` producing the `ffi` error, I've never had this happen to me before. Is `rest-client` deprecated? Or is there a simple solution that I'm not catching onto? I've researched this, and nobody has had this problem (while using `restclient`) however there is a ton of people who have gotten this error while using other gems. For example see also [here](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=cannot%20load%20such%20file%20--%20ffi_c%20(LoadError)%20ruby). It might also be worth mentioning that I'm running Windows 7.

Comment: Does anybody know anything about this information?

Comment: Try with ruby 2.2 if you can. ruby 2.3 seems to be [unsupported](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/500) for the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found an answer to this, it had to do with Holger Just's answer with a minor tweak, I'm pretty sure my case is pretty unique because my company likes to hide behind a VPN script. So here's how I did it:

- First I needed to install the pre-release gem of `ffi` using the platform flag: `gem install ffi --pre --platform=ruby`
- Next I had to update the gem: `gem update --all` (I think that's the correct syntax for the flag)

That got `ffi` working.

Comment: This is strange... The `--pre` flag is not used to select the previous version but to install pre-release gems (if any) Thus `gem install ffi --pre` should install exactly the same gem as would be installed without the flag currently. The only thing I can think of here is that you have proxies or caches providing different gems than the one from rubygems.org and your commands somehow managed to circumvent these (outdated) caches.

Answer (score 2):

The error comes after the `ffi` tries to load its C extension. If we have a look at [the source code of the FFI gem](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/blob/1.9.10/lib/ffi.rb#L3-L7), it tries to load the compiles extension according to the version of Ruby currently running:

```
begin
  require RUBY_VERSION.split('.')[0, 2].join('.') + '/ffi_c'
rescue Exception
  require 'ffi_c'
end
```

The first part fails so it falls back to the `require 'ffi_c'` which also fails. The problem now is that the first part should not fail.

In your case, it seems you are using a FFI gem which was compiled for another version of Ruby. Unfortunately, ruby has changes its ABI during releases so this doesn't work.

Thus, you need to make sure you are either using the pre-compiled gem matching your ruby version (which might be hard to find) or compiling it yourself. For that, please install the [Development Kit](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) for your Ruby version (towards the bottom left of the page). Then, you can install the ffi gem and force it to compile the C-extension on installation:

```
gem install ffi --platform=ruby
```

This is required as `gem install ffi` (without the `--platform` parameter), rubygems first tries to install the gem variant specific to your platform, i.e. mingw32 in your case, which is available in pre-compiled from from rubygems.org. Unfortunately, this precompiled gem apparently is incompatible with your version of Ruby. As such, you can force rubygems to get the source-version of the gem and compile the C-extension on its own. This is what you are instructing rubygems to do with the `--platform=ruby` argument.

This matches the description [in the issues](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/368#issuecomment-56304541) on FFI's issue tracker.

Comment: I already have the dev kit installed. Are you sure that running a platform install will help?

Comment: Still, Ruby first tries to install the (precompiled) gem matching your platform which does not work in your case. If you install the gem with `--platform=ruby`, the extension will be compiled for your current ruby version and probably won't exhibit the issue anymore.

Comment: That doesn't really explain why when I installed the latest version, it did the same thing, I also rolled back, etc, and that didn't help..?

Comment: Alright, I'll give it a shot when I have some time to try it out. Thanks for your help

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? The installation? The `require`? Anything else? Please edit your question and add any error messages / stack traces you get and what you have tried to fix this.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and give you the bounty, I found a solution that involved yours, I think mine is a unique case since the company I work for hides behind a VPN 24/7. It's hard to get gems installed correctly, however this did work with a minor tweak by downloading the previous version of `ffi` using the platform flag, and then updating the gems